# How can I append an array in NumPy using an input function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to work on a program that allows users to add numbers to an array and then perform mathematical operations on the arrays via NumPy but I'm having trouble working out how users can add numbers to the list.

I have a code that is a variation of the following:

```
list = np.array[(1, 2, 3)] 
list = np.append(int(input("Please add a number to the list:")))
print(list)
```

And I want the user to able to input "4" and have it show up at the end of the array like: [1, 2, 3, 4].

Never used NumPy before so I'm unsure as to how a lot of it works. Is there an alternative method I should be using?

Comment: Did you spend any time reading the docs for `np.append`?  Or did you just assume it behaves just like list append?  Either way, I discourage its use.  List append is better - safer and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better idea is to append to list and then convert to numpy array. Appending to numpy array is slower:

```
list = [1, 2, 3] 
list.append(int(input("Please add a number to the list:")))
print(np.array(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`np.append()` works for adding elements

```
list = np.array([1, 2, 3])
## get the number from user
n = int(input("Please add a number to the list:"))
list = np.append(list, n)
list
```

output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
list = np.array([1, 2, 3])
list = np.append(list, int(input("Please add a number to the list:")))
print(list)
```

The output will be like this `[1 2 3 4]`

and you can directly do any arithmatic operation on that array like

```
    list*12
    list+20
    list*[2,4,5,5]  #array multiplication
```

[numpy docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/index.htm) 
let me know is this helpful for you